# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. When trying to do dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm trying to get VirtualBox to work on ElementaryOS with kernel `3.2.0-49-generic`. I've been getting this error :

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-ose-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Failed to open the X11 display!
```

I've searched and found that running :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

Solves the problem.

But when i do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`. I get this error :

```
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.1.12
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.2.0-49-generic
Building initial module for 3.2.0-49-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.2.0-49-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.2.0-49-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.1.12/build/make.log for more information.
```

Now I've checked the `make.log` file i found this error :

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-4.1.12 for kernel 3.2.0-49-generic (x86_64)
Thu Jul 18 05:57:58 EET 2013
make: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.2.0-49-generic/build'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.2.0-49-generic/build
```

I have no idea what should be done from here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do `ls -l` in `/lib/modules/3.2.0-49-generic/` folder you will find that build is a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the  `/usr/src/3.2.0-49-generic`  directory

ex:

```
sagar.sakre@sagar-vm /lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic $ ls -l
total 4412

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 39 Aug  6  2012 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic
```

So make sure that you have the built source code in `/usr/src/` directory. If still problem persists upgrade the kernel.

Comment: Amazing. Worked like a charm. I remember that i've created the `build` directory manually for `vmware-player` to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing the virtualbox via apt-get. So I have solved downloading the [oracle version of virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). Try it:
Remove the virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox
```

Download the virtual box on the oracle website
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Then install

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-version...
```

I hope it works fine for you

Answer (score 0):

If someone has same prob on Debian.

If ls -lah show this

```
toor@tr:/  ls -lah /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Sep 22  2015 build
```

maybe you have same prob as me

this fixes my probleem

```
toor@tr:/ sudo mv /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/build /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/build.bak
toor@tr:/ sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-486 /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/build

toor@tr:/ ls -lah /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jul 24 22:04 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-486
```

after

```
toor@tr:/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-486$ sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
```

And it works.

Thanks to this man **Sagar Sakre**